# Error while accessing nested json using PySpark SQL in Bluemix PySpark Notebook

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have loaded nested json data from Cloudant NoSQL DB using PySpark SQL in Bluemix PySpark Notebook. The nested json data loaded into DataFrame(PySpark SQL). I am able to access the root field values, while accessing the field value from inner json, I am getting the following error. My sample json data is:

> { "name" : "The Lightning Thief", "author" : "Rick Riordan",
>   "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians", "genre_s" : "fantasy",
>   "inStock" : true, "details" : { "price" : 12.50, "pages_i" : 384 } }

```
booksDataDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host","AAA-HOST").\
option("cloudant.username", "BBB-USERNAME").\
option("cloudant.password","CCC-PASSWORD").\
load("books")

booksDataDF.count() # output is 4

booksDataDF.select("name").show() # output as The Lightning Thief

booksDataDF.select("details.price").show() # getting error

messageDF = booksDataDF.select("details.price")

messageDF.select("price").show() # getting error
```

Part of the error stack is as follows:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1343.showString.
>       : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 84.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure:
>   Lost task 0.9 in stage 84.0 (TID 501, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0032):
>   scala.MatchError: 502d9856.afd268 (of class java.lang.String)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:255)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)

I am struck here, help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error stack is: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-1c99ed920def> in <module>()
----> 1 messageDF.select("price").show()

/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    255         +---+-----+
    256         """
--> 257         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    258 
    259     def __repr__(self):

Comment: /usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
814   815         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
43     def deco(*a, **kw):44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
47    s = e.java_exception.toString()

Comment: /usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Comment: Hi Pari. You should add those comments to the original question. Also, have you tried `booksDataDF.select("details.price").show(5)` or  `booksDataDF.show(5)`? Perhaps some row does not have that field.

Comment: Hi @Joss, sorry I was getting formatting issue, thats why I couldn't add those comments in questions itself. Next time I will try to add it in qtn itself. Still I get the same error, 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 8.0 (TID 37, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0038): scala.MatchError: 502d9856.afd268 (of class java.lang.String)

Comment: Looks like some casting problem: /usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

Comment: And with `booksDataDF.first()`? You can also try to get the other fields to ensure that the problem is only **details.price**. If you only have 4 rows, you may check that there are no inconsistencies in the file.

Comment: I ran the code with the example that you published and I didn't found any error.